# Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a class that I have created and put it in a custom folder in the src folder. It is not a nestjs module nor a provider just a helper class that I can instantiate and use. However when I run the app I got the following error:

```
    npm run start:dev

> rent-go@1.0.0 start:dev /Users/arsenegandote/Applications/js/rent-go
> nodemon

[nodemon] 1.18.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /Users/arsenegandote/Applications/js/rent-go/src/**/*
[nodemon] starting `ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/main.ts`
Error: Cannot find module './json.result.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (/Users/arsenegandote/Applications/js/rent-go/node_modules/tsconfig-paths/lib/register.js:75:40)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/arsenegandote/Applications/js/rent-go/src/lib/api.controller.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:30)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/arsenegandote/Applications/js/rent-go/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:733:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/arsenegandote/Applications/js/rent-go/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...](url)
```

This is the generic class I am instantiating in a controller:

```
   export class JsonResult<T> {
      readonly status: string;
      readonly data: T;

      constructor(status: string, data: T) {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
      }
    }
```

And my controller implements this abstract class:

```
export abstract class ApiController {
  failed(): void {
    throw new HttpException(
      {
        status: ApiStatus.FAILED,
        data: {},
      },
      HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    );
  }

  notFound(): void {
    throw new HttpException(
      {
        status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
        data: [],
      },
      HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
    );
  }

  badRequest(message: string): void {
    throw new HttpException(
      {
        status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
        data: {
          message,
        },
      },
      HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
    );
  }

  success<T>(data: T): JsonResult<T> {
    return new JsonResult<T>(ApiStatus.SUCCESS, data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it a TypeScript file? Is the path in your import correct? `./json.result.js`

Comment: @KimKern Yes it is a typescript file.

Comment: @KimKern Thank you for pointing out. It seems the auto-import of Vscode did not work as expected. As I fixed it everything is working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error: Cannot find module './json.result.js'
```

The error means that your file cannot be found. Make sure your import path is correct.